# Alter a form's values on submission but before validate?

Tags: 6, users

I'm trying to set up the user registration form to populate the username field with the email address field. Is there a way to do this without using hook_validate and having to manually do the form validation?

Comment: why do you not want to do this using hook_validate?

Comment: As side note, a form validation handler is not an implementation of `hook_validate()`.

Comment: I want to avoid hook_validate because as I understand it you then have to validate all the fields instead of having drupal handle it for you.

Comment: Drupal will not automatically validate all the form fields for you, except that it will return an error when a required field has not been filled. To validate a form, Drupal will use the validation handlers provided by the modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on what exactly you want to do.

- If you want to pre-populate a form field, then you can implement [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_form_alter/6) (or `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`).
- If you want to avoid users are allowed to set a username for their account, then you should change the form field used for the username in a "hidden" form field, and add a validation handler that set the username to the value you want to use. The reason I would do it in the form validation handler is to avoid that form validation handlers implemented by other modules would throw an error because the field is empty; the error they show would not make any sense to the user, who is not seeing any field for which the error is reported.
- You want to set the username just in the case the user doesn't provide any value. In this case, I would implement `hook_form_alter()` to set the field as not required, and then I would add a form validation handler to set the username in the case the user didn't provide a value for the username.

Comment: So is a form validation handler simply adding a method to the #validate array? Does it execute before or after the default validation?

Comment: A validation handler added with `$form['#validate'][] = 'mymodule_form_validate'` will be executed after the default validation handler. You can add a validation function with [#validate](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/6#validate) or [#element_validate](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/6#element_validate); in the first case you are adding a validation for the form, and in the second case for a form field.

Comment: Awesome. This will come in extremely handy.

Answer (score 1):

[hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_form_alter/6) (or [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/6)) can be used to populate any field before rendering.

Comment: Yeah but I need to alter the field on submit.